# Implementing better search from sqlite android

Tags: android, search, android-sqlite

I am currently using a SearchView to take input and whenever the input changes i call searchVideo()

this is my searchVideo function :

```
public void searchVideo(String s)
    {
        videos.clear();

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("CodifyData", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM appdata_videos WHERE subcode='"+dbName+"' AND title LIKE '%"+s+"%'";
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql,null);

        int idID = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int linkID = c.getColumnIndex("link");
        int titleID = c.getColumnIndex("title");

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            videos.add(new VideoDataModel(c.getString(idID), c.getString(titleID), c.getString(linkID)));
        }

        c.close();

        videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But when user inputs two words and those two works are contained by the title but not next to each other or in a way they are input by the user, the search fails, so what can i do to make this better, don't need a complicated solution but something simpler and easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split your string by space to get array of words 
and concat the values with query like that:

```
String[] splitedValues = str.split("\\s+");
            String query="SELECT * FROM appdata_videos WHERE subcode='"+dbName+"' ";
            for(int i=0;i<splitedValues .length;i++){

                    query+="AND title LIKE '%"+splitedValues[i]+"%' ";

            }
```

Comment: Instead of OR won't it be better to use AND ?

Comment: No, if use "AND" and one of expression fail  the query will fail

Comment: so that would be better to get a precise search result right ?

Comment: yes if want to find the matches of all words  in one title

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Works like a charm